# html passing parameter to form and auto-selecting a value in the select box

Tags: html, wordpress, forms, parameters

I have a page on which I put a button:

http://s1064857.instanturl.net/mstainless.com/portfolio/pass/

When clicked, I want the click to redirect to

http://s1064857.instanturl.net/mstainless.com/request-quote

and have the select control automatically selected.  I tried putting in a parameter into the button URL as .../request-quote?Product=Cabinets

but when the target page is loaded, the Product SELECT control is not set.

The code block for the form is as follows:

What am I missing here?

Comment: have you tried `<option selected="selected">` on the option you want to be default selected?  So when the page loads it will select that option.

Comment: Also there is no code in your code block.  Please show us some code.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  Basically, the page doing the calling has ?Product=Cabinets on the URL, and the target page is one in Wordpress created using Contact Forms 7.  The select code is

   [select Product class:input-style class:dlight-grey class:sc-input include_blank "Cabinets" "Carts and Ladders" "Pass Throughs" "Sinks" "Tables and Benches" "Miscellaneous"]

So if "Cabinets" is passed to the target page, I'm trying to have "Cabinets" automatically selected.

Answer (score 0):

While you haven't had provided any code I think I get what you are wanting.  When you send the following GET: .../request-quote?Product=Cabinets

You will need to use the following code to get the Product GET variable and use it to determine which option should be selected by default in your .

```
<?php
//Get the Product variable from the URL
$product=$_GET['Product'];

//Start a <select>
echo "<select>";

//If the $product is Cabinets then make it the default option
if ($product=="Cabinets") {
    echo "<option selected='selected'>Cabinets</option>";
}
//Else do not make it the default option
else {
    echo "<option>Cabinets</option>";
}

//NOW DO THIS FOR EACH PRODUCT.  HERE ARE A COUPLE EXAMPLES

if ($product=="Desks") {
    echo "<option selected='selected'>Desks</option>";
}
else {
    echo "<option>Desks</option>";
}

if ($product=="Chairs") {
    echo "<option selected='selected'>Chairs</option>";
}
else {
    echo "<option>Chairs</option>";
}

//End the <select>
echo "</select>";

?>
```

Now this will make the $product the default selected option in the .